# Celebrate Joi validation with Express using Router

Tags: node.js, express, joi

The [documentation](https://github.com/continuationlabs/celebrate) shows how to use celebrate in the app's main file. My routes are already handled by express Router and it is separated from the index file where I have my app's setup.

I would like to set up a validation for the request body on a post route. The example in the docs shows how to do the setup in the main file, and this part confuses me because I have the routes separated in a different file and I'm using `router.post('/')` instead of `app.post('/')` due to the usage of Express Router.

Where should I put

```
const { celebrate, Joi, errors } = require('celebrate');
```

and

```
app.use(errors());
```

To the main index file or to my routes file?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to put `const { celebrate, Joi} = require('celebrate');` at the top of your routes file

Then you can use celebrate in your routes for validation

```
router.post('/', celebrate({
  body: Joi.object().keys({
    name: Joi.string().required(),
    age: Joi.number().integer(),
    role: Joi.string().default('admin')
  })
}), (req, res) => {});
```

In your index file add to the top of your index file

```
const { errors } = require('celebrate');
```

then at the end

```
app.use(errors())
```